# How to order fields returned by a PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I Have 3 tables names like `companystructure,projectallocation,introducermaster`

I have tried this

```
select *
from
(
select projectallocation.proAllocationID as Sno,
       introducermaster.intro_name as IntroLow,
       temp.intro_name as IntroTop,
       projectallocation.introtoplevelEmpid as TopEmp,
       (companystructure.csshortname) as Level,
       projectallocation.introlevelEmpid as EmpID 
from projectallocation
inner join dbo.IntroducerMaster 
ON dbo.introducermaster.empid=projectallocation.introLevelEmpid 
inner join introducermaster as temp  
on temp.empiD =projectallocation.introtopLevelEmpid
inner Join companyStructure 
ON companyStructure.HLevel = projectallocation.introleveID 
where projectallocation.projectID=1
group by IntroducerMaster.Intro_Name,
         temp.intro_name,
         companyStructure.CSShortName,
         projectallocation.proAllocationID,
         projectallocation.introlevelEmpid,
         projectallocation.introtoplevelEmpid
) b
PIVOT
(
    max(introlow) for level in(CH,ED,DIR,GM,AGM,BDM,SMM)
)PVT

Output
Sno         IntroTop                                           TopEmp                                             EmpID                                              CH                                                 ED                                                 DIR                                                GM                                                 AGM                                                BDM                                                SMM                                                
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- 
177         NANDI RAMA                                         EMP00093                                           EMP00006                                           NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               ALAGAPPAN
178         EDWART                                             EMP00031                                           EMP00012                                           NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               NULL                                               B.MURUGESWARI
```

i want the empid will became last at the pivot table

Answer (score 2):

You should order returned fields in your first SELECT statement in this way:

```
select Sno, IntroTop, TopEmp, [CH], [ED], [DIR], [GM], [AGM], [BDM], [SMM], EmpID
from
(
)
pivot
(
)
```

Example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE pvt (VendorID int, EmpID int, EmployeeID int, Orders int);
>
> INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (1,1,10,5);
> INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (2,1,11,5);
> INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (3,2,10,5);
> INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (4,2,11,5);
> INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (5,3,10,5);
>
>
> SELECT VendorID, COALESCE([10],0) [10], COALESCE([11], 0) [11], EmpID
> FROM 
> (
>     SELECT VendorID, EmpID, EmployeeID, Orders FROM pvt
> ) src
> PIVOT
> (
>    SUM(Orders) FOR EmployeeID IN ([10],[11])
> ) pvt;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> VendorID | 10 | 11 | EmpID
> -------: | -: | -: | ----:
>        1 |  5 |  0 |     1
>        2 |  0 |  5 |     1
>        3 |  5 |  0 |     2
>        4 |  0 |  5 |     2
>        5 |  5 |  0 |     3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=422a89ae2fb441051dacc2399b093578)*